# Add swipe gestures in addition to MotionLayout transition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-motionlayout, android-gesture, android-touch-event

I am using a MotionLayout setup with a `dragUp` Transition to toggle some layout on my view. (Basically you can drag up to see more information.)  However, I would also like to be able to support "swipe left" and "swipe right" gestures to trigger other things in the app, but I cannot figure out how to listen for the swipe events without breaking my MotionLayout transition.

If I set an OnTouchListener on my view I can see the swipe events, but this seems to break the  MotionLayout transition since I can no longer drag up for the extra info.

I think I might need some way to "pass through" swipe events in my OnTouchListener when they are up/down, but just calling `super.onFling...` does not seem to work. Otherwise I am hoping there is a different way to implement this swiping functionality that I have not stumbled across yet...

Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add more ConstraintSets and Transitions that go between them like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/middle">
        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/square"
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"/>
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/middle"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/left">
        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/square"
            app:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            app:touchAnchorSide="left"/>
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/middle"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/right">
        <OnSwipe
            app:touchAnchorId="@id/square"
            app:dragDirection="dragRight"
            app:touchAnchorSide="left"/>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/square">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/middle">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/square" >
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/left">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/square" >
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/right">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/square" >
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

If you want to see a fun working example [here's a sliding tile puzzle I did](https://github.com/kaeawc/motion-puzzle).

Comment: Thank you!  Some how I had convinced myself that only one transition was possible. After checking out your sliding tile puzzle and watching your excellent presentation here https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=362742385 I was able to get things working!

Comment: Sweet, glad that helped :)

Comment: Multiple transitions on a single motion scene layout is not working for me(constraint layout 2.1.4) Any idea?